# node, express - Listen for Remote Browser Reload

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

Quick question about a (maybe) weird use case:

I have a remote sensor that provides an API to its readings over the local network, via `<ipaddr>/json`. I'm using a quick `expressjs` server and grabbing the response over AJAX, all good. Unfortunately, the sensor doesn't display any historical data over this API, but only one object with the most recent readings.

I would like to store a series of results -- probably 100 of the most recent -- and calculate aggregates. My first thought is to do this on a timer, the feed reloads every ~5s. But on second thought, it'd be much nicer to listen for some sort of event that express can use to fire the AJAX call.

Is this at all possible? I don't have any control of client-side code, so `socketio` would probably not work. Are there any other ways to poll for reloads?

Comment: I suppose it all depends on your sensor API.  If we don't have socketio, I know of only two ways: webhooks and Server-Side Events (where your sensor would be the server).  I have never met SSE in the wild myself. Webhooks are very common: you would have to see in the documentation if there is a way to configure the sensor to call an arbitrary URL with the relevant data and let it call your express code that way.

If you point me to the documentation I can have a quick look.

Comment: Thanks for your help @tgo! Unfortunately, no official docs for the sensor and no control over any code on the sensor side, but I'll share some links here in case you see something worthwhile. [google doc documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15ijz94dXJ-YAZLi9iZ_RaBwrZ4KtYeCy08goGBwnbCU/edit#heading=h.l6r1b1hpfhod), [purple air sensor](https://www.purpleair.com/sensors), [google group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/weewx-user/hzN9K3QH7kU/v4ETARANBQAJ)

Comment: I also just found this, and it looks like it's being done on a timeout as well. Seems like that may be the way to go! [py extension](https://github.com/bakerkj/weewx-purpleair/blob/master/bin/user/purpleair.py)

Comment: interesting. I think that you indeed don't have any other option and your first idea looks good. Using setInterval() or some such... Good luck